# how to group an array by dynamic key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, ecmascript-6

so i have an array in that i want to group values by given id , i have tried a method but its not working for dynamic key .
this is my array

```
let employees = [{"employeeDetail": [{"empID": "XXYYZZ11","firstname": "abc","joinedAt": "13/04/2014", "address": "VVGGHHNN" }],"employeeSalaryDetails": [{"month": "Jan","salaryAmount": "35000","Bank": "XXXXX","PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"}]},{"employeeDetails": [{"empID": "XXYYZZ11","firstname": "abc",   "joinedAt": "13/04/2014","address": "VVGGHHNN"}],"employeeSalaryDetails": [{"month": "Feb",  "salaryAmount": "35000","Bank": "XXXXX","PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"}]},{"employeeDetails": [{"empID": "XXYYZZ22","firstname": "abc",   "joinedAt": "13/04/2014","address": "VVGGHHNN"}],"employeeSalaryDetails": [{"month": "Jan",  "salaryAmount": "35000","Bank": "XXXXX","PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"}]}]
```

I want this array to be like this

```
[{"empID": "XXYYZZ11","firstname": "abc","joinedAt": "13/04/2014","address": "VVGGHHNN","employeeSalaryDetails": [{"month": "Jan","salaryAmount": "35000","Bank": "XXXXX","PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"}, {"month": "Feb","salaryAmount": "35000","Bank": "XXXXX","PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"}]},{"empID": "XXYYZZ22","firstname": "abc","joinedAt": "13/04/2014","employeeSalaryDetails": [{"month": "Jan","salaryAmount": "35000","Bank": "XXXXX","PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"}]}]
```

I have tried this method ,it work for employeeDetails key ,but i want to resuse this method ,if **employeeDetails** is **details** in employees array ,it should work ,but by method is not working

```js
    let employees = [{"employeeDetail": [{"empID": "XXYYZZ11","firstname": "abc","joinedAt": "13/04/2014", "address": "VVGGHHNN" }],"employeeSalaryDetails": [{"month": "Jan","salaryAmount": "35000","Bank": "XXXXX","PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"}]},{"employeeDetails": [{"empID": "XXYYZZ11","firstname": "abc",   "joinedAt": "13/04/2014","address": "VVGGHHNN"}],"employeeSalaryDetails": [{"month": "Feb",  "salaryAmount": "35000","Bank": "XXXXX","PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"}]},{"employeeDetails": [{"empID": "XXYYZZ22","firstname": "abc",   "joinedAt": "13/04/2014","address": "VVGGHHNN"}],"employeeSalaryDetails": [{"month": "Jan",  "salaryAmount": "35000","Bank": "XXXXX","PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"}]}]

    function employeeGroup(empArray, key) {
       return Object.values(empArray.reduce(
          (obj, { employeeDetails: [item], employeeSalaryDetails }) => {
             (obj[item[key]] = obj[item[key]] || { ...item, employeeSalaryDetails: [] })
                .employeeSalaryDetails.push(...employeeSalaryDetails)
                return obj
       }, {}))
    }
    console.log(
    employeeGroup(employees,'empID')
    )
```

I need this `employeeDetails: [item]` to be dynamic one,if employees array have **details** instead of **employeeDetails** .I need `details: [item]` this to be dynamically change,Note there is not data structure for **employees** , any help ?

Comment: input and output looks the same.  you might need to clarify it better

Comment: oh, I thought you wanted something more complicated.  it looks like the only thing you want is to pass the entire array to the new object?  change [item] to details and use details[0] instead of item, and change ...item to employeeDetails: details

Comment: @user120242 check now

Comment: I have tried as you said but its not working, can u pls post the answer ?

Comment: Are you saying that the key will sometimes be employeeDetail or employeeDetails?  Or saying that it might even be detail or details or employeeDetail or employeeDetails or someotherkeyname?  Is there a pattern?  How should the program determine if it is the right key?

Comment: @user120242 emeployeeSalaryDetais key is same for all the array passed to this method ,but employeeDetails will be some time details that's it .

Comment: your current array has the key employeeDetail instead of employeeDetails.  Is that on purpose?  It still isn't clear what you are asking for here.  Do you want the key name employeeDetails to be configurable?  Or do you need it to detect the name automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Just tries to extract both employeeDetails and details, trying to use the one that exists.

```js
let employees = [{"details": [{"empID": "XXYYZZ11","firstname": "abc","joinedAt": "13/04/2014", "address": "VVGGHHNN" }],"employeeSalaryDetails": [{"month": "Jan","salaryAmount": "35000","Bank": "XXXXX","PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"}]},{"employeeDetails": [{"empID": "XXYYZZ11","firstname": "abc",   "joinedAt": "13/04/2014","address": "VVGGHHNN"}],"employeeSalaryDetails": [{"month": "Feb",  "salaryAmount": "35000","Bank": "XXXXX","PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"}]},{"employeeDetails": [{"empID": "XXYYZZ22","firstname": "abc",   "joinedAt": "13/04/2014","address": "VVGGHHNN"}],"employeeSalaryDetails": [{"month": "Jan",  "salaryAmount": "35000","Bank": "XXXXX","PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"}]}]

function employeeGroup(empArray, key) {
   return Object.values(empArray.reduce(
      (obj, { employeeDetails: [item1]=[], details: [item2]=[], employeeSalaryDetails }) => {
         const item = item1 || item2
         ;(obj[item[key]] = obj[item[key]] || { ...item, employeeSalaryDetails: [] })
            .employeeSalaryDetails.push(...employeeSalaryDetails)
            return obj
   }, {}))
}

    console.log(
    employeeGroup(employees,'empID')
    )
```